# in es6, make an event listener with a callback into an iterable

Tags: javascript, iterator, listener, generator

my websocket class, `Wws`, listens to all incoming messages using `onmessage`.

for programs using `Wws`, my websocket module, I would like them to "listen" through `iterable`s.

for example,

```
// listen for new blog messages
let itr = ws.listen( 'blog', 'new' );

// display each new blog as we receive it
while( true ) {
  let blog = itr.next().value;
  dispBlog( blog );
}
```

any number of `iterable`s might be hanging on the event listener.

how would you write the `generator` in the `ws` module?

```
ws = function() {
  conn = new Websocket(...);

  // could have global `onmessage` that passes through the messages
  conn.onmessage = function(msg) {
    // can look at listeners and know there are iterators
    // but how to talk to them?
  }
  listeners = new Map();

  // generator for listening to incoming messages
  listener = function*( service, action ) {
    // can add this service.action to listeners, but what?
    // does this guy create his own `onmessage`?
    // if so, how does he get the `yield` to the outer function?
  }
```

how do you convert a `listener` with a `callback` into an `iterator`?

Comment: `for… of` is blocking. It would prevent your server from doing anything else as long as you're in that loop, including accepting new requests. You don't want to do that.

Comment: @Touffy - thanks - did not know that. changed into `then()`

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this via the following example class:

```js
// A class that wraps a `WebSocket` to allow you to `await` on messages.
// Useful for blocking until a message is received, and continuing to listen
// afterward.
export class WebSocketMessageGenerator {
    private receivedMessages: Data[] = [];
    private wait: Promise<void>;
    private waitResolve?: () => void;
    private generator: AsyncGenerator<Data | undefined, void>;
    private closed = false;
    constructor(private readonly client: WebSocket) {
        this.generator = this.messages();
        this.wait = new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
            this.waitResolve = resolve;
        });

        this.client.on("message", (data: Data) => {
            this.receivedMessages.push(data);
            if(!this.waitResolve) {
                throw new Error("waitResolve is undefined");
            }
            this.waitResolve();
            this.wait = new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
                this.waitResolve = resolve;
            });
        });

        this.client.on("close", () => {
            this.closed = true;
        });
    }

    public async * messages() {
        while (!this.closed) {
            if (this.receivedMessages.length > 0) {
                yield this.receivedMessages.shift();
                continue;
            }
            await this.wait;
        }
    }

    public async nextMessage<T>(): Promise<T> {
        const message = await this.generator.next();
        if (message.done) {
            throw new Error("No more messages");
        }
        if (!message.value) {
            throw new Error("No message");
        }
        return JSON.parse(message.value.toString());
    }
}
```

calling like so:

```js
const generator = new WebSocketMessageGenerator(new Websocket("url"));
const data = await generator.nextMessage();
```